# Why can't i run the client side of this simple server-client app more than once?

Tags: java, client-server

Here's the code for server side :

```
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 8080;
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket cliSocket = server.accept();

            Scanner in = new Scanner(cliSocket.getInputStream());

            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(cliSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            String message;
            while((message=in.nextLine()) != null){
                write.println(message+" added");
            }

            write.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

and here's the client side :

```
public class EchoClient {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String ip = "localhost";
  int port = 8080;

  try {
    Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
    PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    while((input=read.nextLine()) != null){
        write.println(input);
        System.out.println("sent by server:" + in.nextLine());

    }

    write.close();
    in.close();
    read.close();
    client.close();


} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}



}

}
```

Now when I run the server and then the client, it works. But if close the client app, and i run it once again, the server won't allow connection.

What is the solution in situations like this?

Comment: Your server app can only attend to a single client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is that every time you accept a connection, you launch a new thread to handle the client. That would allow you to handle any number of clients, and also deal with general TCP issues like sockets that are stuck open when clients are killed.

Something like this:

```
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 8080;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {

            //wait for next client to connect
            Socket cliSocket = server.accept();

            //hand off socket to another thread
            MyHandler handler = new MyHandler(cliSocket);
            Thread clientHandler = new Thread(handler);
            clientHandler.start();    
        }
    }
}

public class MyHandler implements Runnable {

    public MyHandler(Socket cliSocket)
    {
        //store socket
    }

    @override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true) {
            //handle client comms
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server program only accepts one client connection and exits after handling the connection.

If you want it to repeatedly accept client connections, you need to use a loop around the code you have in `main()`